# Why does flexbox push my image to the side of the my logo?

Tags: html, css

i have been trying to insert a image of a dog in my css with flexbox but every time i try it goes directly to the side of my logo(title) here is the code (thanks for the help):

```
<html>
    <header>
        <div class="logo">
             <h1>Doggies</h1>
        </div>
            <nav>
            <ul>
        <div class="list">
            <li>Learn</li>
            <li>Images</li> 
            <li>Submit Photo</li>
            <li>Creator</li>
        </div>
            </ul>
            </nav>
    </header>
    <body>
        <div class="alaskan">
          <img src="alaskan.jpg">  
        </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>

css=
.logo{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
nav{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.list li{
    display:inline-flex;
    margin:10px 5vw;
}

body{
    display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your header tag should be placed within your body tag. Don't confuse the header tag (should be in the body) with the head tag (should be outside the body). The body tag encompasses all of the content on the DOM. Even if you place the header tag outside of the body tag as you are doing now, the body still considers it as part of the body. To test this, if you add "background: red" to your body with your current code, you will see that the entire screen including behind the header content will have a background of red. That's why when you added "display: flex" to the body, it made all of the content (including the header) sit side-by-side.

Here, I just moved your header into the body and removed the "display: flex" on your body css. If you want to make the body content display flex, create a separate div inside the body just for the content and add display flex to that div.

```css
.logo {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: red;
}
nav{
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: blue;
    
}
.list li{
    display:inline-flex;
    margin:10px 5vw;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <header>
          <div class="logo">
               <h1>Doggies</h1>
          </div>
              <nav>
              <ul>
          <div class="list">
              <li>Learn</li>
              <li>Images</li> 
              <li>Submit Photo</li>
              <li>Creator</li>
          </div>
              </ul>
              </nav>
      </header>
      
       <div class="alaskan">
          <img src="alaskan.jpg">  
       </div>
    </body>
    
    </html>
```